# how to set the editor correct indentation and code formatting policy in xamarin studio 5.0

Tags: xamarin, indentation

In Xamarin Studio 5.0.1(build3).

I input the code in the editor, when I enter `ENTER`, why the indentation is too long, and the `{` symbol is not align to the `if` keyword, and `int i = 3` is not aligned to the above line?

This is a visual representation of what is happening:

```
        if (mUri == uri)
            {
                   mImageView.Image = image;
                           int i=3

             }
```

xs perferences:
  behavior=> indentation mode: smart (also try option: none, automatic)
  SourceCode/Code formatting: c# source code/ Policy: has been try the following options: mono/visual studio/custom/tab width:4 ...

The same setting is Xamarin Studio 4.3 are ok.

I also try to uninstall xs5.0 and reinstall it, but not resolved.

It also will be happen for any new projects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, the settings are available in Options dialog under Source Code | Code Formatting | C# source code tab, where you can apply existing policies, or define your own via C# format tab (click Edit button there to launch the customization dialog). Any change you made will trigger a preview. Since you did not provide any screen shot on your current settings, I bet nobody can give you an answer at all.

Comment: I think that this has been fixed. I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.8.3 (April 2015) and the "Whitespace" option under Source Code | Code Formatting | Text File works fine. I used e.g. for Tab width and Indent width "2" (instead of 4). You just need to restart Xamarin Studio. It works.

Comment: This issue cannot be reproduced anymore using Xamarin Studio 6.1.3 (build 19).